# How to translate: "the person near whom i fell" with relative pronoun

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

In order to translate "the person near whom i fell" a relative pronoun is needed, which one?
Forms of lequel replace things. Therefore should you use qui?

la personne près de qui je suis tombé --or--
la personne près de laquelle je suis tombé

Answer (score 0):

Both forms are equally possible, the shorter been the most usual, especially in casual speech.